Thunderbird not able to open HTML attachments in firefox
I am running Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS and Thunderbird 115.16.0esr (64-bit) on a fully up to date system. As of recently, when I click on an .html file attachment in Thunderbird and ask it to open the attachment in firefox, it fails. Firefox reacts, but it says Firefox can’t find the file at /tmp/pid-4036/site.html. I thought it might be a snap permission issue, but I am using the .deb package for thunderbird. Is this perhaps an issue with the firefox snap?
Does anyone understand where my problem might be coming from? I am out of ideas as to how to diagnose the problem.

I just noticed that .docx attachments (going to libreoffice) do open, but .html files going to firefox and .png or .jpg files going to the default image viewer do not.

does this article offer any guidance?

No, I don't think so. That article is about HTML emails (i.e., emails with HTML content in them), I am talking about .html files attached to an email (which I just happen to be receiving in this moment). Yesterday it was also other attachment types that didn't work, but today (after a reboot) it is just .html files that fail because firefox can't find the temporary file. Perhaps this is an issue with the firefox snap?

Oh yes... Snap can be a b****.
Try to add Permissions for the Firefox-Snap and Thunderbird-Snap to read/write files outside the Snap-Container:
sudo snap connect thunderbird:removable-media
sudo snap connect firefox:removable-media

Thanks for the suggestion. I ran sudo snap connect firefox:removable-media, restarted firefox and gave it a try, but it still doesn't work. Thuderbird is not a snap, so I do not think that is the issue.

I think the bug report here seems to be this same issue, but regarding accessing temporary files generated by firefox in libreoffice. There are a huge number of comments in this thread and it is hard to see a solution, but somehow this way now works between firefox and libreoffice. Is it me, or is this an incredibly complicated way of doing things? Shouldn't sharing files between applications be doable in 2024?
